# SQL How to check if N records in a row meet condition?

Tags: sql, select, timestamp, db2

I've got data from sensors and I need to generate an alarm if values are higher than constant for 10 records in a row (I have value and timestamp). If less then reset the counter. I use DB2. There is a short piece of the table. If e.g. 3 values in a row higher than 1 - write to another table an alert

```
Value   Timestamp
2   09.09.2017 0:01
6   09.09.2017 0:04
0   09.09.2017 0:07
7   09.09.2017 0:10<-from here
2   09.09.2017 0:13
6   09.09.2017 0:16->to here
1   09.09.2017 0:19
```

For the sample, the output should be a period when it's out of range

```
START   09.09.2017 0:10
END 09.09.2017 0:16
```

Comment: If your DB engine has triggers, use that. Triggered on insert simply write the required sql to fetch the records. Then a where clause to test for any not out of tolerance - if you get any result then the "10 in a row" criterion is not met.

Comment: @radarbob I need to analyze existing dataset, there's no insert to trigger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can identify groups of rows that are in sequence by counting the number of values that do not exceed the threshold up to that point.  This is constant for a sequence that exceeds the threshold.  The rest is just aggregation:

```
select min(timestamp), max(timestamp), count(*) as num_in_sequence
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when value <= 1 then 1 else 0 end) over (order by timestamp) as grp
      from t
     ) t
where value > 1
group by grp
having count(*) >= 10;
```

Comment: That's marginally neater than writing a procedure

Comment: Gordon, could you tell why we use less or equal in sum(case...? Value has to be higher than a threshold to be counted

Comment: @KirillDrozdov . . . That counts the number that do *not* exceed the threshold.  Run the subquery to see what it assigns to the rows.